# Using Chebyshev's Inequality with Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm currently looking at a proof in Royden's Real Analysis which applies Chebyshev's inequality in a way I'm not quite understanding. In particular, $$\int_{\{x\in A\, \mid\, f(x) \geq c\} } f \leq \frac{1}{c} \int_E f$$ where $f$ is nonnegative and integrable over $E$, $A\subseteq E$ is measurable, and $c>0$.

Note: This question has been posted before and an alternative proof of the claim was given, but there was no explanation for the above inequality.

Comment: Looks more like Markoff's inequality than Chebyshev's. It's just the observation that $f-c\chi_B\ge0$ when $B=\{x\in A:f(x)\ge c\}$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng So how does one arrive at the above inequality given your observation?

Comment: Are you sure there's no typo? Take $A := E := (0,1) \in \mathbb{R}$, and $c = 2 = f(x)$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. Then LHS $= 2$ while RHS $= 1$.

Comment: @mathdoge That is how it is written in Royden's text.

Comment: What/which theorem is it trying to prove ultimately? I think the example I gave is a counter-example.

Comment: @mathdoge It's in the section on uniform integrability. It's prop. 23 in Royden if you happen to have the text.